# Deploying Record IDs in Flow Tests

Tags: visual-workflow, record-type, test-automation, recordtriggeredflow

I have a record triggered flow and wanted to try the new Flow Test feature. I implemented a test and when I downloaded the metadata I noticed that the Record Type ID is hard coded. When I deploy these tests on different sandboxes the IDs will change and effectively break the test. Is there a "work around" for this shortcoming?

Comment: Can you redesign your flow so that it queries for the RecordType by DeveloperName?

Comment: @cropredy The issue isn't in the flow but in the flow test. You are asked to set an object as input and from the metadata it seems that the record id of the object is hard coded in the xml.

Comment: your OP mentioned recordtypeId so I was confused

Comment: Also if flowtest data has reference to lookup fields, for that also it is fetching Id instead of Lookup field data.